# An integral involving hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

$$ \large \displaystyle \int_0^\infty {\dfrac{e^{-2x} \tanh\frac{x}{2}}{x \cosh x}dx} = 2 \ln \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} $$

How to prove the above integral?

What I tried :

$\displaystyle I(s) = \int_0^\infty {\dfrac{e^{-sx} \tanh\frac{x}{2}}{x \cosh x}dx} $

$\displaystyle I'(s) = -\int_0^\infty {\dfrac{e^{-sx} \tanh\frac{x}{2}}{\cosh x}dx} $

$\displaystyle I'(s) = L [sech x](s+1) - L [sech \frac{x}{2}](s+\frac{1}{2}) $

where $L[f](s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(x)$ as a function of $s$.
But after this I don't follow much. Finding the laplace transform and then integrating doesn't seem a better approach.

Comment: In general, one can show that $$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a x}\tanh\frac{x}{2}}{x\cosh x}dx = 2 \ln\left(\large \frac{ \Gamma(a) \Gamma\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)^2}{2^{\frac{a+1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to compute:
$$ I  =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x(e^x+1)(e^{2x}+1)}\,dx =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2x}+1}-\frac{1}{e^{2x}+e^{x}}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$
that is the same as computing
$$ J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2(1-t)^2}{(1-t^4)\log t}\,dt.$$
Since $\frac{t^2(1-t)^2}{1-t^4}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(t^{4k-2}-2t^{4k-1}+t^{4k}\right)$ and [$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^\alpha-1}{\log t}\,dt = \log(\alpha+1)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html),
$$ J = \sum_{k\geq 1}\log\left(\frac{(4k-1)(4k+1)}{(4k)^2}\right)=\log\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{16k^2}\right) $$
where the value of the last infinite product can be recovered from:
$$ \frac{\sin z}{z}=\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2 k^2}\right)$$
by setting $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Is there no "straighter" approach? That substitution seems quite too random.

Comment: To set $x=\log t$ in a integral that strongly depends on $e^x$ does not look so *random* to me, anyway you may also avoid that step and skip from the first centered formula to the third one by directly applying Frullani's theorem.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thanks!